# Delete leaves in a tree with regex (Python)

Tags: python, regex, tree, nlp

I have a syntax tree, saved in a text file in a "LISP-style", with open and closed brackets that show relations. I want to delete all leaves. For example, I have " (Det the)" that I want to become " Det". I'm not expert of regex, so I wonder how I could handle this behaviour in a more complex structure, with nested brackets. An example of tree (in my file is in one row, is indented just for a simpler visualization):

```
(S
  (NP I)
  (VP
    (VP (V shot) (NP (Det an) (N elephant)))
    (PP (P in) (NP (Det my) (N pajamas)))))
```

I would have something like:

```
(S NP
  (VP
    (VP V (NP Det N))
    (PP P (NP Det N))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
re.sub("\((\w*) (\w*)\)", r"\1", t)
```

where t is the variable holding your syntax tree.

For unicode support, see the comments below.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I would ask you a little more help if possible: I need to have support with unicode character, I did a little test, and for example "è" is naturally not detected by \w (that's only [a-z]). How could I handle this?

Comment: @AndreaRomagnoli: See [re.UNICODE](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=re#re.UNICODE) in the Python `re` docs.

Comment: If someone is going to need the UNICODE version out-of-the-box, here is the solution: tree = re.sub( r"\((\w*) (\w*)\)", r"\1", unicode( tree, 'utf-8' ), flags=re.UNICODE )

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
import re

tree1 = """(S
  (NP I)
  (VP
    (VP (V shot) (NP (Det an) (N elephant)))
    (PP (P in) (NP (Det my) (N pajamas)))))"""

tree2 = re.sub("\(\s*(\w+)\s*(\w+)\s*\)", r"\1", tree1)

print(tree2)
```

Output:

```
(S
  NP
  (VP
    (VP V (NP Det N))
    (PP P (NP Det N))))
```

It probably would be better to use `\s*` instead of just  (space) in regex - it will allow you to have sequences of zero or more whitespace characters (spaces, tabs and newlines) within the substrings representing the leaves.

[link to online Python repl](http://repl.it/fv1/2)

[link to regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aP0rK3/1)

Comment: As well as allowing newlines, the `\s*` allows multiples of any white space characters (simple spaces, tabs, newlines, etc) in the string, which may also come in handy. :) See the entry for `\s` under [Regular Expression Syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=re#regular-expression-syntax) in the Python `re` docs for details.

Comment: Ok, now meaning of `\s` and `*` is explained.